The Clinton administration or Clinton's administration
Can you, please, explain why we say the Clinton administration, not Clinton's administration?

Because the reference is to the administration of that presidency not to the administration belonging to that president.  But we might say "Clinton's Attorney General", for example, because then the reference would be to the A.G. Clinton nominated or "hand picked", and the possessive expresses that idea.

In this module, you can explore some of the conflicts that arose during President Clinton’s administration -- 'Commander in Chief' section of the William J Clinton Presidential Library and Museum.

It's not that the possessive is impossible but that the possessive, in focusing on the person of the president, doesn't express the idea of "during the Clinton presidency".  It's the William J. Clinton Presidential Library, after all, and its focus will be on the person of William J. Clinton.

The form with the apostrophe is sometimes used.  Eg, on Wikipedia:

Terrorism emerged as an increasingly important national security issue during Clinton's administration. In the closing years of the Soviet–Afghan War Osama bin Laden had organized al-Qaeda, a militant Sunni organization.

Why is it not used more often?  It's just a matter of idiom with no real logical reason.

When you refer to a person and his/her organization, you an use the possessive, the of version of use the person's name as an attributive adjective (some might say noun):

Tony Blair 's government
OR

the government of Tony Blair
OR

the Tony Blair government

He also served as Chancellor of the Exchequer in the Tony Blair government from 1997 to 2007.
Express

Sir Michael was the inaugural Head of the Downing Street Delivery unit in Tony Blair’s Government between 2001 and 2005.
Strand Group


This works for administration or organization or party or dictatorship or rule (for a king or queen), etc.

Thank you all very much!
